Powermail: Export Fieldmarker (Variables) instead of Field labels
I want to make use of the export command task of powermail. That works, but i need the field marker(custom variables) not the field label as column name. I created a new template file as suggested here
I want to adapt the ExportXsl.html. I tried to change
<vh:String.RemoveQuote><vh:Getter.GetFieldLabelFromUid uid="{fieldUid}" /></vh:String.RemoveQuote>

to
<vh:String.RemoveQuote><vh:Getter.GetFieldMarkerFromUid uid="{fieldUid}" /></vh:String.RemoveQuote>

but this does nothing. What can be done?

the viewHelper Getter.GetFieldMarkerFromUid exists, so I'd consider to report it as bug.

Thank you, i was thinking the same, but it is also possible i just missed something :)

Is it a "normal" field that is shipped with the extension? Normally you should get a marker (or at least a generic one) - if the field-object has a getMarker-method.

They should all be standard fields. I will check on the getMarker method

I have just cloned the current powermail version, started it up via ddev initialize && ddev start, added the VH call to the export template and exported the supplied data set of PID 118 - the marker name came out in the XLS as well

Question is if the marker is always shown with this viewHelper or only if individually assigned -- in contrast to the markers powermail assigns automatically (which could be on the fly, without storage in the database, but I haven't verified it obviously).

Thats good to know that it works on a more recent version. i guess i have to upgrade then :)
